# Play/Scala SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I'm getting this error on set up play framework on windows

```
sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8
```

error msg:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Unexpected response status 504 fetching metadata from https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:%22org.scala-lang%22+AND+a:%22scala-library%22&rows=10&wt=xml&core=gav
```

Set Up info:

```
$ java --version
openjdk 11.0.17 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.17+8 (build 11.0.17+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.17+8 (build 11.0.17+8, mixed mode)
```

```
$ sbt --script-version
1.9.0
```

I want to set up play framework in windows successfully.

Comment: did you just run `sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8`, moved to the root directory of the project, then execute `sbt run` and you got that error? did you edited your `build.sbt`, `plugins.sbt`, `build.properties` or any other file? Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? based on that only error message, sounds like you are using SLF4J and you haven't provided any logger implementation such as logback, log4j or any other compatible one

Comment: I think OP gets this error when running `sbt new`. The slf4j error is not a big deal, you can ignore it. The second error message is weird and sounds like a network potentially temporary issue.